# Reducing space between bars in a visual studio report project chart

Tags: reporting-services, business-intelligence

I'm putting together a report project in VS2012 for which the values are aggregated by month and by a second category. The result I'm getting is this:

[image]

The result I'd like to get is this:

[image]

Does anyone know how I can reduce the space between bars for just one category grouping in a report in Visual Studio 2012?

Thanks.

PS - to be clear, there are no series groups in this graph - only sum values and category groups.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you can't do this. I asked the question on the MSDN forums as well, and was informed that this functionality specifically does not exist within SSRS.

In the chance that anyone is interested, you can view the forum thread here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c6da786d-b747-4b57-ab46-65f1aa769f79/closing-gap-between-columns-in-report-chart-within-their-category-grouping?forum=sqlreportingservices#d44b59e0-1643-4085-bad6-acbfc678b1d6